# OpenLayers removing/adding marker (airplane): update the orientation based on lat/long (next point in database)

Tags: openlayers-2, json, markers

The code below I have is working great. I'll try to explain it in a few lines (btw you can view it here http://codeshare.io/9Z1BE):

-there's a marker on the map. The lat long is returned as json from a database. There is only ever ONE marker on the map at any given time.

-Say marker is at position A. Stays there for 2 seconds, goes to position B. B to C. C to D. So on and so on. This A-B-C-D represents a flight path: ie, 'A' would be the origin, and 'D' would be the destination (say LAX to JFK).

-Now I would like to have the orientation adjust accordingly based on where the marker is going. Say you were flying from Sydney to Hong Kong: you're moving north. The marker/airplane should have a north orientation.

-After googling a bit it seems it's better to use a vector feature than a layer feature so you can use the rotation property. But how exactly do I implement this with the setTimeout function below?

```
    var map;
    var updateMarker = "";
    var markers;
    function init(){
      map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
        controls: [
          //controls here
    ],
         numZoomLevels: 10
    });
    markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
    map.addLayers([layer1]);
}

function planeDelay() {
setInterval(function() {
$.ajax({
  url: "latlong.php",
  type: "POST",
  success: function(msg){
    var json_coords = eval('('+msg+')');
    if(updateMarker != "")
    {
            markers.removeMarker(updateMarker);
    }
    updateMarker = new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(json_coords.longitude, json_coords.latitude));
    markers.addMarker(updateMarker);
  }
});
}, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out finally. I guess using vectors isn't too bad after all :)

http://codeshare.io/9Z1BE

I just referred to heading in the `new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector` in the `rotation` attribute and all worked well.

```
point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(json_coords.longitude, json_coords.latitude);
airplane = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point, null, {
  externalGraphic: "aircraft-s4.png",
  graphicWidth: 50,
  graphicHeight: 50,
  rotation: json_coords.heading
});
vectors.addFeatures([airplane]);
```